# Segregate every second group into 1 or 2 groups SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of multiple components that all have a model number. I want to group every second component based on the model it belongs to.

```
Model | Component | Group
  1         1         1
  1         2         2 
  1         3         1 
  1         4         2 
  1         5         1
  2         1         1 
  2         2         2 
  2         3         1
```

Every second component belonging to a model should have an alternative group number.

I believe I have to use a windows function but haven't been able to solve.

Comment: WHat is your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed that your `Model` and `Component` ID numbers will not be perfectly incremental, but that they will be unique.  As such, you can use the `row_number` windowed function along with the `modulo` operator `%` to get the remainder of the division of the `row_number` result by 2:

```
declare @t table (Model int, Component int);
insert into @t values (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,1),(2,2),(2,2);

select Model
      ,Component
      ,case (row_number() over (partition by Model order by Component) % 2)
         when 1 then 1
         when 0 then 2
         end as [Group]
from @t;
```

Output:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+
| Model | Component | Group |
+-------+-----------+-------+
|     1 |         1 |     1 |
|     1 |         2 |     2 |
|     1 |         3 |     1 |
|     1 |         4 |     2 |
|     1 |         5 |     1 |
|     2 |         1 |     1 |
|     2 |         2 |     2 |
|     2 |         2 |     1 |
+-------+-----------+-------+
```